# http.ListenAndServe: Close when program exits

Tags: http, go

I want to write simple REST API application. I wrote the code handling HTTP-requests:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "movies/dao"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

var d = dao.MoviesDAO{}

// AllMoviesEndPoint show all movies
func AllMoviesEndPoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "not implemented yet")
}

func init() {
    d.Server = "127.0.0.1"
    d.Database = "movies"
}

func main() {
    //d.Connect()
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/movies", AllMoviesEndPoint).Methods("GET")

    go func() {
        if err := http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }()
}
```

But when I run this prgram under debugger and then stop it, socket is bind'ed, I can access server from browser, and I can not run program another time since I get a error `listen tcp :3000: bind: address already in use`.

How to close connection when program exits?

Now I need to `kill -9 PID` my server to start new debug session.

Comment: What debugger are you using, how are you starting it, and what do you mean by "stop it"?

Comment: @Adrian, Delve debugger with VS Code. "and what do you mean by "stop it" selec Stop Debugging

Comment: Your program is invalid: `http.ListenAndServe` call blocks but the goroutine you're starting to run it on does not synchronize with the goroutine running `main()`; when the latter exits, all the other active goroutines are teared down. The fact your program appears to hang there in some half-assed state is probably an artefact of it being debugged by `delve`, but the program is still invalid: should you just build it and run as is, it would immediately quit.

Comment: @typemoon I think you should add graceful shutdown for your http, like mentioned here:
https://github.com/gorilla/mux#graceful-shutdown

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the debugger, the problem is in your code.

When you write

```
go func() {
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":3000", router); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}()
```

you're creating a new goroutine that's completely independent by the main thread.

This means that the execution of your main is:

1. Create router
2. Create and execute a goroutine
3. end of main, return and kill all childs

There's nothing making the main waiting for the go routine execution and termination.

Since `http.ListenAndServe` creates a thread that waits indefinitely for new connections, you don't need to create it inside a goroutine.

Hence, just remove the `go func() {` block and you'll be ok.